# Как взять список из одинаковых view-компонентов

Tags: android, view

Можно ли каким-то образом взять массив, к примеру, TextView, которые есть в конкретной активности или необходимо каждую вьюшку брать отдельно?

Comment: Не вполне понятен вопрос. Возможно, вы имеете в виду что-то типа `findViewsByIds(R.id.id1, R.id.id2, R.id.id3, R.id.id4)`? Если да, то такого нет.

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно это вам поможет.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221135/how-to-get-all-views-in-an-activity

Comment: И для кучи одинаковых вью, скорее всего, лучше использовать списочный контейнер (ака `RecyclerView`, `ListView`, `GridView`, ...).